# NSOutlineView, expansion and collapsing can cause cells to clip content

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nscell

I am experiencing weird visual artefacts during rapid expansion and collapsing of a view based NSOutlineView's groups. If a group is expanded, and I double click (collapse followed quickly by expansion) the expand arrow, the content is clipped. 
My cells contain a simple image and a label to the image's right, and on rapid expansion, the textfield is clipped in some cases, and squashed in other cases, as though the cell when being collapsed gets a zero width frame and doesn't re-expand.
I have altered the auto-resizing masks for the cellView, the outlineRowView, the column, but no combination appears to change the behaviour.

Has anyone come across similar strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `setNeedsDisplay:YES` on the views after they have been unfolded? 
This will tell the view to redraw itself.